# Trying to update Values in Standard Object from metaData

Tags: triggers, salesforce, metadata, apex, apex-code

I am using Trigger `isBefore`

In `System.debug(opp.get(metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c)`, it is showing correct Values but not Updating in `Opportunity Object`

Below is `Trigger` and its `Apex Class Trigger`

`Trigger`

```
trigger MetadataObjectFieldMapping on Opportunity (before insert, before update) 
{
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate )
    {
        MetadataObjectFieldMappingHandler oppHandler = new MetadataObjectFieldMappingHandler();
        oppHandler.Show(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

And `Apex Class`

```
public class MetadataObjectFieldMappingHandler {
    List<String> strAccField = new List<String>();
    //Getting List of MetaData Values
    List<Object_Field_Mapping__mdt> metaData = new List<Object_Field_Mapping__mdt>
                                                        ([SELECT Account_Field_Name__c,
                                                             Opportunity_Field_Name__c 
                                                                 FROM Object_Field_Mapping__mdt]);
    //Function to check if Field Name Exists in Object or not
    public Boolean hello(String objName, String fieldName)
    {
        Boolean temp = False;
        //Creating Schema to get all fields from Account and Opportunity Object
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> accFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();     
        for(Schema.SObjectField field : accFields.values())
        {
                    strAccField.add(field+'');
        }
        //Calling Account and Opportunity Object in fieldName
        if(strAccField.contains(fieldName)){
            System.debug('PASS '+fieldName);
            temp = true;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    public void Show(List<opportunity> newOppList)
    {       
        Boolean test1 = hello('Account',metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c);
        Boolean test2 = hello('Opportunity',metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c);
        //If both Field Value exists
        if(test1 && test2){
            //Getting value from Opp using dynamic Query
            String query = 'Select Account.'+metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c+', '+metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c+' from Opportunity where Id IN : newOppList ';
            List<Opportunity> oppList =database.query(query);
            for(Opportunity opp : oppList){
                opp.put(
                    metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c, 
                    opp.Account.get(metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c)
                );
                System.debug(opp.get(metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c));
            }
        }
}
```

Can you please tell me, why Value is not Updating in `Opportunity Object` while it showing in `Debug Logs`..?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple fails here I think.

Apex is case-insensitive when you do `if('a' == 'A')`. But when comparing Strings in collections (Lists, Sets, Map keys) it suddenly becomes case-sensitive.

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>{'Id', 'Name'};
System.debug(fields.contains('name')); // false
```

(this should have been a `Set<String>` by the way, for performance and logical readability). So I suspect something's fishy there, in case. You didn't show your metadata but check this one (you have only 1 row now, right? If you have more than one - we'll your `metaData.get(0)` essentially returns a random row).

I don't like the cast from `Schema.SObjectField` to String either.

---

Next: `String query = 'Select Account.'+metaData.get(0).Account_Field_Name__c+', '+metaData.get(0).Opportunity_Field_Name__c+' from Opportunity where Id IN : newOppList ';`

This has a chance of working in `before update`. But for sure not in `before insert`. Nothing's in database yet, your query will return zero results. You have to loop through trigger.new, collec AccountIds, query Accounts (directly, not via Opportunity table) and then make final loop that writes data.

---

You passed `newOppList` to `Show()`. If you want to get the save to database for free - you should modify values on the original, on `newOppList`. Instead you modify the in-memory results of query (`oppList`). Nothing will happen to them, they'll be discarded. If you want to save them, you'd have to do it manually (but then you risk entering a loop of update triggers and SF will stop you).

---

You sure this has to be code? Sounds like a job for workflow or process builder. Or make them formula fields so you always display fresh value instead of such copying... When something changes on Account it won't automatically cascade down to all opps unless you make next trigger/process builder...

Comment: Yes, I know this can be done by Process Builder but my Task is to this Using Apex and Custom Metadata  will have only one record.